# If there are 10 parents and 8 teachers nominated for positions on the school council, how many different committees can there be?

Tags: permutations, combinations

A school council consists of 12 members, 6 of whom are parents, 2 are students, the Principal and the remainder are teachers. The school captain and vice-captain must be on the council. If there are 10 parents and 8 teachers nominated for positions on the school council, how many different committees can there be?

Comment: "school captain and vice-captain" - who are these?

Comment: The correct answer is 11760

Comment: These are part of the students

Comment: This means that both student positions are taken, so you can say you need to select 10 out of the remaining pools.

Comment: Please write descriptive titles. We get lots of "permutations and combinations" questions everyday.

Comment: I did (10C6 x 10C3 x 10C1), but it is the wrong answer. Should I add instead, or are my numbers incorrect?

Comment: If I understand, we have four blocks:  Parents, Students,  Principal,Teachers.  The Student block is fixed, no options.  As is the Principal.  We need $6$ parents and have $10$ to choose from, hence $\binom {10}6$.  We then have six parents, two students, and one principal set, so we have three teacher slots and eight to choose from, hence $\binom 83$.  Thus $\binom {10}6\times \binom 83$ all in all.  Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: Yes thank you!!